# Can I filter a Web Part list using parameters from the URL?

Tags: 2013, web-part, jslink

In my rich content area I've inserted a Pages Web Part (to show a list of pages in the subsite). I'm using JS Link to customize the presentation of the list.

Can I pass a parameter to the page and use that to filter the list in someway?

/directory.aspx?company=7eleven

or

/directory.aspx?year=2014

Comment: Even if its Pages Web Part, you can still edit the web part properties and edit the view. Follow the steps I have outlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Query String (URL) Filter.

1. Insert the web part on your page.
2. Open the web part options and name the parameter (company or year from your example).
3. Give it a default value if you'd like.
4. Then use the web parts connections and connect it to your list.

   - Under the connection options choose "Send filter values to".
   - Select your field name that you want to filter on.

[image]

Comment: I can edit web part properties, but I don't see anything about parameters. I'm using (Web Part > Apps > Pages).

Comment: Add the Query String (URL) filter web part first then set the properties on that web part.  You'll see a parameter name there.  Then connect that web part to your list.

Comment: Web part is located at Web Part > Filters > Query String (URL) Filter

Comment: I don't see Filters under Web Part.

Comment: Added picture of how I add web part.

Comment: I definitely don't see Filters. Is that a publishing site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18061/discussion-between-matt-and-jordan).

Comment: Got the answer from another question. I had to enable, SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features.

Answer (score 7):

Modify the view using browser and do following

- Select column from the filter (company)
- Select contains
- Enter {company}
- Or
- Select column from the filter (year)
- Select contains
- Enter {year}

Save and close.

Now open SharePoint designer and edit the view aspx file in advanced mode. Look for

```
<ParameterBindings>
```

and add following

```
<ParameterBinding Name="company" Location="QueryString(company)" />

<ParameterBinding Name="year" Location="QueryString(year)" />
```

Save and close. Open the page in browser and go to

```
/directory.aspx?company=7eleven&year=2014
```

Comment: This works brilliantly on the view page. E.g. if the view is called MyView this will work: /site/lists/ListName/MyView.aspx?Filter1=Value1. But I'm trying to get this to work on a Wiki page where I've added a list view web part for ListName, which is connected to another list view web part on the same page. On this wiki page when I select MyView as the view to use in the list view web part for ListName I get an error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it. For anyone stumbling across this issue, the `<ParameterBindings>` need to be added under the `<XsltListViewWebPart>` tag in the WIKI PAGE, not just `MyView.aspx`. Your answer, Amal, does not require SharePoint Enterprise, so props to you. Thanks!