# Where is Query String (URL) Filter?

Tags: 2013, filter, query-string

Based on the answers to a [previous question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118764/can-i-filter-a-web-part-list-using-parameters-from-the-url) I want to use the Query String (URL) Filter, but I don't see it on my site. Is there something I have to enable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter web parts require enabling SharePoint Enterprise site collection feature. That means this belongs to only enterprise SharePoint versions.