# How to do filter using QueryString in web part sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list-view

I referred this [Can I filter a Web Part list using parameters from the URL?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118764/can-i-filter-a-web-part-list-using-parameters-from-the-url) link but its not working.

What to do?

Comment: What is not working in your case? You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: it is not filtering based on the query string .. instead it shows blank

Comment: If list view webpart is blank, means it worked and didn't found any item after applying filter.

Comment: How many paramaters  you are using in your URL?