# Display specific listview depending on url

Tags: list, view, url

I would like to display a specific list view depending on URL.
I have just one list and one page.
If my url is http://server/pages/[TOTO], it will be display items which have one column value = TOTO for example
Then in the same page http://server/pages/[LOREM] will display items which have one column value = LOREM

Does it possible on SP2013 ? Using JSlink or something else ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to create custom views on different pages?

Comment: Hello, no I would like to use the same page but with a property URL to display different view depending on this property

Comment: What do you want to show depending on the query string? Different views or same view with different filter parameters? Because I understand that from your question, you want to filter list items depending on URL value, not to change view, such as column count or column order.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Query string to pass filters to your list view.... For e.g

Create a view of your list....below urls with querystring will filter data automatically... Replace ColumnName with your actual column name..

```
MyURL.aspx?FilterField1=ColumnName&FilterValue1=TOTO

MyURL.aspx?FilterField1=ColumnName&FilterValue1=LOREM
```

Please note here Query string parameters name and value are case sensitive, you need to make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto @Siddharth Vaghasia, you can use the Query String (URL) Filter web part to filter based off those URL parameters. You can connect the web part to any list.

See the answer to the question [Can I filter a Web Part list using parameters from the URL?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118764/can-i-filter-a-web-part-list-using-parameters-from-the-url) for a bit more detail.